# Performance Implications of Wildcard indices

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I'm trying to do an update by query call to elasticsearch, which requires me to update certain files from multiple indices.

Since the exact name of each index isn't known, I have to use a wildcard character.

**Example**:
index: friends-*

Is there any non-negligible performance implications towards this?

Comment: What's missing is how many indices map to `friends-*` and some idea of the volumetry? If that's a small number of indices or 1000, the performance may vary greatly.

Comment: @Val It can be a significant amount since essentially each user will have their own friends-* index

Comment: wow, one friends index per user... how many docs per index do you have?

Comment: @Val Max 250 friends per user, so max 250 documents

Comment: Geez, then you should definitely put all of them into a single index and not have that many indices for so few documents. Case solved.

Comment: @Val Thanks so much for the recommendation. I'm using update by query in another way with wildcard indices, this one can have unlimited docs in each index.

Do you have any links or any recommendations on what do when docs in an index grows to too much? Would I need to split an index or something along those lines?

Comment: It always depends on the definition of "too much"... Hardware matters, settings and mappings matter, use case matters, ... Feel free to provide more info about your exact use, otherwise "too much" doesn't mean much...

Comment: @Val Our documents are super small, maybe less than 100-200 bytes. In particular they contain two fields, a uuid and username. The mapping to this username is completion, no special analyzer. In terms of hardware, we're using ElasticSearch cloud so we don't have a set hardware.

Comment: I addition to what @Val mentioned, the recommended size of a shard is around 40-50 GB. Anything above that will start to see performance degradation. Also too many shards will lead to issue. That is the general idea, hope this helps.

Comment: So you can store a few billion documents in your index if they have only a few fields :-)

Comment: Yeah, that s the idea. Elastic optimise documents in the same index. You have really no reason to make different index if mapping is the same (until a certains amount of data of course). Dont forget es's index use separated shards ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the help guys